# A system-breaking code is added after the text I type in Ckeditor

Tags: html, ckeditor

I am adding a new article to my website, but a code like this is added after the article;

`<div class="bootstrapiso notranslate" data-html="true" data-original-title="" id="mttContainer" title="">&nbsp;</div>`

Does anyone know what this means? How can I fix this? Also, every time I update the code, another one is added instead of the one that is separated.

I did research but couldn't find a useful resource.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this HTML element is added by one of your Chrome extensions, in your case it is Mouse Tooltip Translation extension.

Please checkout [the source code here](https://github.com/ttop32/MouseTooltipTranslator/blob/6051c147bdee077a9fde8051e624537ec40197bb/src/contentScript.js#L213)

[image: #mttContainer insert location]